# Autocomplete through a selected external key (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a query and I have 2 models, one called **Detalleventa** and **Producto**

```
class DetalleVenta(models.Model):
  producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Producto')
  cantidad = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Cantidad')
  preciounit = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, verbose_name='Precio unitario')
  subtotal = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, verbose_name='Subtotal')
  venta = models.ForeignKey(Venta,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='detalleventa', verbose_name='Venta')

  def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.venta,self.producto)

class Producto(models.Model):
  nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,verbose_name='Nombre de Producto:')
  precio = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7, verbose_name='Precio de Producto:')
  categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Categoría:')

 def __str__(self):
   return self.nombre
```

And in my **Detalle** forms.py I have:

```
 class DetalleForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
   model = DetalleVenta
   fields = [
    'producto',
    'cantidad',
    'preciounit',
    'subtotal',
   ]
   labels = {
    'producto':'Producto',
    'cantidad':'Cantidad',
    'preciounit':'Prec.Unit.',
    'subtotal':'Subtotal',
   }
   widgets = {
    'producto':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    'cantidad':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control cantidad'}),
    'preciounit':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    'subtotal':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control subtotal', 'readonly':True}),
}
  DetalleFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Venta, DetalleVenta,
                               form=DetalleForm, extra=1)
```

As you can see in the details form, I have a priceunit field that refers to the price of the product that is in the product model and my question is: is there any way in my details template when selecting, for example, a product X ? ? (external key product) autocomplete its respective price in the input of preciounit?

This is my template:

```
 {% extends 'base/base.html' %}
 {% load static %}
 {% block titulo%} Registrar venta {%endblock%}
 {% block contenido %}
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
<label class="font-weight-bold" for="{{form.cliente.name}}">{{form.cliente.label}}</label>
{{form.cliente}}
</div>
<h4 class="text-left">Detalle de venta: </h4>
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
    <table class="table" id="tablaDetalle">
        {{ detalleformset.management_form }}
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th width="100px">Cantidad</th>
            <th width="115px">Prec.Unit.</th>
            <th width="115px">Subtotal</th>
            <th>Acción</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for form in detalleformset.forms %}
            <tr class="formset_row">
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <td>
                        {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                {{ hidden }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                        {{ field }}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-end">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <label class="font-weight-bold" for="{{form.total.name}}">{{form.total.label}}</label>
    {{form.total}}
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="font-weight-bold" for="{{form.descripcion.name}}">{{form.descripcion.label}}</label>
    {{form.descripcion}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit"><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
      </span>Registrar venta</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
    {% endblock %}
```

As you know, it's for a small sales system and I have to get the price of the product. If there is a way to be able to do what has been proposed? or at least a clue to discover how to do it?

Comment: Do JS calls here is no way to make it work only with Django templates.

Comment: what? You mean if there is a way to do it with the django template?